# Map markers not getting captured in screenshot

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, html2canvas

I have been trying for a while on how to capture screenshot of a map. Finally managed to get in working on Chrome using Html2Canvas, capture screenshot functionality.

```
            $('#map_canvas').html2canvas({                 
               proxy: "server.js",
               useCORS: true,
               onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    //Set hidden field's value to image data (base-64 string)
                    $('#img_val').val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));                    
                }
            });
```

I was initially missing the proxy and useCORS property.
Now the problem is that only the base map is captured and the markers that are plotted on them are not getting captured. Same is the case with the overlays on map. they are also not captured. How can i get this to work???? Any help would be great!!!

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I suspect the issue is that only the base tile layer is rendered via a `<canvas/>`. Markers and Overlays are simply DOM elements rendered on top of the base tiles.

Comment: I believe the only legal way to display an image/screen capture of a Google Map is to use a static map (but IANAL).  Have you verified you can do this legally by checking the [TOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos)?

Comment: Hi! My answer solve your problem? If so check as "correct", if not tell me what is missing.

Comment: See this answer as a workaround:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/29897324/2652861

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26402789/html2canvas-combine-2-captured-canvases-into-one

Answer (score 2):

**server.js** is only for servers with **[node.js](http://nodejs.org/)** (is a technology for server-side and not client-side).

`useCORS: true` not work with `proxy: "proxy-script-server"`.

Or you use `useCORS:` or use `proxy:`

I recommend using **proxy**. I developed 3 scripts to use proxy, all do the same thing, but each is in a different programming language.

Proxy scripts:

**ASP.NET (C#)**:
https://github.com/brcontainer/html2canvas-csharp-proxy

**PHP**:
https://github.com/brcontainer/html2canvas-php-proxy

**ASP classic (vbscript)**:
https://github.com/brcontainer/html2canvas-asp-vbscript-proxy

**Python (works with any framework)**:
https://github.com/brcontainer/html2canvas-proxy-python

---

Example with PHP:

```
html2canvas( [ document.body ], {
    "proxy":"html2canvasproxy.php",
    "onrendered": function(canvas) {
        var uridata = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        window.open(uridata);
    }
});
```

> note: SVG images can not be added to the *CANVAS* and then exported
>   with `.toDataURL()` in the current **Google Chrome (version 29)**

Comment: can you give example with python. I am also having same issue.

Comment: @Gulherme_Nascimento Ya I have seen the python proxies too. But I confused how to use it :(

Comment: @BhimPrasadAle Python with `mod_python` or `mod_fastcgi` or `uWSGI` or `mod_wsgi` or `django`?

Comment: @Guilherme_Nascimento I am using python flask.

Comment: @BhimPrasadAle As I understand the ["Python Flask"](http://flask.pocoo.org/) is a framework that does not use conventional servers, yourself creates the connection and the answer, I'm sure (like "node.js")? Your problem is not with the "proxy".
It seems that your problem is a lack of understanding of framework (python Flask). Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: ya I know I am missing something but still not able to figure it out. about flask I am just a newbie.Will update you if I figure it out.

Comment: @BhimPrasadAle Note that the proxy in python developed by "Niklas von Hertzen" uses "Google Appengine" you got me interested in developing a proxy with better documentation. If you can wait.

Comment: ya I tried to use that proxy using "Google Appengine" but didn't find any connection on my project. It would be great if you develop it :) . Hope it would help me too. :)

Comment: @BhimPrasadAle I create um lib in python, work with any framework. I added an example with Flask works for you to see and adapt to your needs.

Comment: thank you. I will let you know after I checked it. :)

Comment: I am geting "GET http://127.0.0.1:5555/home/bhim/remo/App/images/a0af53c02bd2f2aed37f1d895edcf3485117c512.png [HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND 3ms]"
In the image folder I have the file of the above name. Is there the routing problem ?

Comment: @BhimPrasadAle Create a question with details and your source-code. Note: `virtual_path` need "relative path" and non "absolute path"

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009869/google-map-screen-capture-is-not-working-for-marker-and-marker-cluster-using-htm