# Export google map heatmap layer as PDF

Tags: javascript, google-maps, pdf, export, heatmap

I have implemented a heatmap on the google map using google map javascript API.You can see the code section following

```
  function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 14,
            center: {lat: -33.865143, lng: 151.209900}, // longitude and latitude of initial map center point
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            minZoom:4
        });
        setupHeatMapData();
    }
 function setupHeatMapData(){
        heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            data: heatmapdata,
        });
        heatmap.setMap(map);
 }
```

This is snapshot of the heatmap layer,

[image]

But thing is, I want to export heatmap layer as image or PDF.I hope a solution for that.

Comment: One suggestion I might have is to see if you might somehow be able to get the base64 image data for that heatmap. Then take that base64 and use jdPDF to render it in a PDF.

Comment: Actually disregard my above comment, this is probably the strategy you would follow, where you convert html to pdf (you can also do this with jsPDF): https://htmlpdfapi.com/blog/export_google_map_to_pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find solution for my question.I like to share with all community.basically I use two JavaScript liabries.They are [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) and [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/http://). jsPDF use to render pdf by placing text,images. and html2canvas library use to create canvas object by selecting jquery element in html. we can create canvas object by selecting div tag as well. please go through following steps

```
<div class="row map-containner"><div id="map"></div><div>

<script src="js/jspdf/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jspdf/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
```

***// JAVA SCRIPT CODE***

```
        var element = $('#map');
        var pdfOptions = {
            orientation: "landscape", // One of "portrait" or "landscape" (or shortcuts "p" (Default), "l")
            unit: "mm",              //Measurement unit to be used when coordinates are specified. One of "pt" (points), "mm" (Default), "cm", "in"
            format: "legal"            //One of 'a3', 'a4' (Default),'a5' ,'letter' ,'legal'
        };

        var doc = new jsPDF(pdfOptions);

        var pageWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.width-20;
        var width  =  pageWidth;

        html2canvas(element, {
            useCORS: true, // MUST
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                var imgWidth = element.width();
                var imgHeight = element.height();

                var height =  (pageWidth * imgHeight)/ imgWidth
                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL(
                        'image/png');
                doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 30 , width, height);
                doc.save('heatmap.pdf');
            }
        });
```

In this case we can render heatmap and map into pdf
but there is problem on rendering markers on google map into PDF.we can find solution on this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009869/google-map-screen-capture-is-not-working-for-marker-and-marker-cluster-using-htm). Please share any good solution to export google markers also into PDF

Answer (score 1):

Hope you can use following ways to resolve your issue.

1. html2canvas : http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/
2. jsFeedback :http://experiments.hertzen.com/jsfeedback/
3. google map image api : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/imageapis/